# draw a round rectangle with gradient

Tags: java, swt

I want to draw a round rectangle in SWT like this one

[image: gradient]

I couldn't found a way to do this, and I decide to throw my code away and ask here :(
any thoughts?
Thanks :D

**Edit**
I tried again, this is what I have for now

```
 import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
    import org.eclipse.swt.events.PaintEvent;
    import org.eclipse.swt.events.PaintListener;
    import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Color;
    import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas;
    import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
    import org.eclipse.wb.swt.SWTResourceManager;

    public class TesteGradient extends Canvas {
        Color COLOR_TOP = SWTResourceManager.getColor(166, 166, 166);
        Color COLOR_BOTTOM = SWTResourceManager.getColor(241, 241, 241);

        private boolean selected = false;

        public TesteGradient(Composite parent, int style) {
            super(parent, style);

            this.addPaintListener(new PaintListener() {
                public void paintControl(PaintEvent e) {
                    e.gc.setAntialias(SWT.ON);

                    e.gc.setBackground(COLOR_BOTTOM);
                    e.gc.setForeground(COLOR_TOP);
                    e.gc.fillGradientRectangle(0, 0,93, 27, true);
                    e.gc.setClipping(0, 0, 4, 4);
                }
            });
        }

        public boolean isSelected() {
            return selected;
        }

        public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
            this.selected = selected;
        }

}
```

Comment: Is your code really thrown away?  If it's possible to retrieve what you've tried so far, that might be helpful.

Comment: I didn't commited what I tried, lost the history of the file. i'm sorry

Comment: If you are using Eclipse, there might be a chance to recover it.  Right-click file -> Compare with -> Local History.

Comment: done: https://github.com/germantech/ios-checkbox-swt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The corret URL is https://github.com/germantech/ios-widgets. We've built a small suit of components

Comment: Looks cool! The rounded corners always appears to be not so well defined in SWT. Is there a workaround for that?